# why " attribute error: module PIL has no attribute Image" raises unlike its installed and code is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package, attributeerror

I'm new in python; I install the pillow package with pip and try to import that in my code but when I run the code it's shows   AttributeError: module PIL has no attribute Image.
here is my code:
import PIL

```
with PIL.Image.open("before1.jpg") as Im:
    Im.show()
```

I reinstall python and pillow but nothing change;
I try it with pillow 8.0.0 but nothing change;
previously I have same problem with pytest

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it like this
`from PIL import Image` so that it can find the Image class

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working

Comment: are you using different virtual environments for your projects maybe? Check with pip freeze if PIL has been installed